# How to use malloc in asm

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64, nasm

I'm trying to use malloc to allocate memory dynamically in asm Intel x86_64 with nasm, but I don't understand how to use it.

For exemple, if y want to allocate a 8 bytes memory area, should I push 8 on the stack and then call malloc, like this ?

```
extern _malloc

section .text
    global _my_function

_my_function:
    push 20
    call _malloc
    ret
```

Or should I move 20 to the rdi register, which is the normally the function's first argument like that ?

```
extern _malloc

section .text
    global _my_function

_my_function:
    mov rdi, 20
    call _malloc
    ret
```

I tried both but none of them worked and I didn't find any malloc documentation for nasm.

I'm trying to use malloc in order to recode the strdup function from the string library, here's my actual code :

```
extern _ft_strlen
extern _ft_strcpy
extern _malloc

section .text
    global _ft_strdup

_ft_strdup:
    push rsi
    push rdi                ; rdi = str
    call _ft_strlen         ; rax = ft_strlen(str)
    mov r9, rdi             ; save rdi (str) into r9
    mov rdi, rax            ; rdi = len
    inc rdi                 ; rdi = len + 1
    call _malloc            ; rax = new_str (allocated)
    cmp eax, 0              ; if malloc failed
    je _failure             ; └──► return NULL
    mov rsi, r9             ; rsi = str
    mov rdi, rax            ; rdi = new_str
    call _ft_strcpy         ; ft_strcpy(new_str, str)
    pop rdi
    pop rsi
    ret

_failure:
    xor rax, rax
    pop rdi
    pop rsi
    ret
```

```
section .text
    global _ft_strcpy

_ft_strcpy:
    push rdi
    push rsi
    jmp _loop

_loop:
    mov r8b, BYTE [rdi]     ; Save *dst into r8b
    mov r9b, BYTE [rsi]     ; Save *src into r8b
    cmp r9b, 0              ; if *src == '\0'
    je finish               ; └──► exit from _loop
    mov [rdi], r9           ; *dst = r9 (r9 = *src)
    inc rdi                 ; dst++
    inc rsi                 ; src++
    jmp _loop

finish:
    mov [rdi], r9           ; *dst = r9 (r9 = *src = '\0')
    pop rsi
    pop rdi
    mov rax, rdi            ; rax = initial value of dst
    ret                     ; Return rax (dst pointer)
```

```
section .text
    global _ft_strlen

_ft_strlen:
    push rdi
    xor rax, rax            ; rax = 0
    jmp _loop

_loop:
    cmp [rdi], byte 0       ; if *str == '\0'
    je finish               ; └──► exit from _loop
    inc rax                 ; rax++ (len)
    inc rdi                 ; str++
    jmp _loop

finish:
    pop rdi
    ret                     ; Return rax (len)
```

When I call ft_strdup, I get a `SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000000` error from sanitize.

I call the function this way :

```
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    char new_str = ft_strdup(av[1]);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Yes, show all the code as a [mcve]. Also use the debugger to pinpoint the error and work backwards to what caused it. That said, `mov rdi, 20; call _malloc` should be fine. Note the return value is in `rax` not just `eax` so for  `NULL` check you'd have to test that (but it's not the cause of your problem). Also unclear what `mov rax, r12` is supposed to do. Furthermore according to standard calling convention `rdi` is caller-saved so you can't rely on its value after `_ft_strlen`. Same goes for `r9` across your call to `_malloc` which is likely your problem.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to remove the `mov rax, r12` statement, my bad, let me edit the post to add others functions

Comment: What operating system are you programming for?  Please add an appropriate tag.

Comment: @fuz and why is that? Looks correct to me. Also it works. The problem, as I said, is `malloc` destroying `r9` which he used to save the string pointer.

Comment: Yes, it was ! You can post the answer ! I just added a `push r9` statement before the _malloc call and a `pop r9` after it, it worked

Comment: rdi is not preserved; so if that works, it happens to work.   The source string is already saved on the stack at the function prologue.

Comment: @Jester I missed OPs attempt to use `rdi` for the argument when I made my first comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution - [jester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/547981/jester)

#### Malloc usage for Intel x86_64 with nasm

- Bytes to malloc go into the `rdi` register.
- Returned pointer to memory region in the `rax` register.

```
mov rdi, 20
call _malloc
```

According to [standard calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) you cannot rely on the value of `rdi` after calling `_ft_strlen`, the same goes for `r9` after calling `_malloc`. This is because both registers are [caller-saved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Caller-saved_(volatile)_registers).

To preserve the value of `r9`

```
push r9
call _malloc
pop r9
```

#### Assembly Programming tips

- show all your code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
- Use a debugger to pinpoint your error and work backward to what caused it ( you could use [gdb](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) with a cool [.gdbinit](https://github.com/cyrus-and/gdb-dashboard) file )

Comment: Note that the ABI requires RSP be 16-byte aligned before a `call`.  In otherwise-equal functions, a single `push` would misalign the stack.  Normally compilers reserve space once at function entry to spill/reload stuff with `mov`, not `push`/`pop` around single calls.  If you want a value to survive across a call, normally you'd just keep it in a call-preserved register like RBX or R15 (which you save/restore once around your whole function, not once per call inside your function)